# Generating the ogp tags in theme

Tags: themes, tags, facebook, open-graph

I use to generate the [ogp tags](http://ogp.me) in themes I code but this commercial one is beyond my knowledge. The client want to share a page but any image option shows up.

Instead of a `taxonomy-name.php` template file, this theme rely on a page templates, where user choose the category/taxonomy to display the gallery from. Problem is: I can't get the attachments as the gallery renders after the query, I do will ask the theme autor to implement this but right now I need to fix this some way.

**Info**

- [Page template](http://pastebin.com/SXbY9A2Y)
- [Theme in question](http://themeforest.net/item/photolux-photography-portfolio-wordpress-theme/894193)

Comment: Okay, that wasn't very clear. So, you just want to show different opengraph meta tags for different pages? Something like this? http://pastebin.com/kVZ1aiyY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is a `page` the global `post` object is already set when `wp_head` fires. But you have to get the data for this page with custom code.

Pseudo code:

```
add_action ( 'wp_head', 'wpse_58539_get_ogp' );

function wpse_58539_get_ogp()
{
    if ( ! is_page_template( 'your-template-name' ) )
    {
        return;
    }

    $page = get_post( $GLOBALS['post'] );

    // Inspect the page meta data to find the taxonomy and the images.
    // print the OGP data

    return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Toscho! This are good news! I will try something here.