# the_title(); works in a page template, outside the loop. Why?

Tags: loop, get-the-title

Trying to wrap my head around the loop concept...

Given a template page (page-work.php) with just this code:

```
<?php the_title(); ?>
```

WP correctly shows the title of that page. As I understand it, this is outside any loop and shouldn't work (Codex says to use `get_the_title` in those cases).

So the question is, why does it work?

Funnily enough, this won't output the title + content, just the title:

```
<?php the_title(); the_content(); ?>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The global `$post` object exists already for singular views before `wp_head` is called. It is just not filled with all data.

The `the_title()` calls `get_the_title()` which in turn calls `get_post()`. And *that* calls `$GLOBALS['post']` if no post ID has been passed.

See also [Generating the ogp tags in theme](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/58539/generating-the-ogp-tags-in-theme) for a use case.

Comment: I see! So this has to do with the global `$post`, not the loop. So much new stuff for me :) Thanks a lot! By the way, do you know of any online resource where I can learn more about the WP globals and the rendering/processing order of WP? The order in which WP assembles everything. I get completely lost at the Codex sometimes and English is not my primary language so searching for that is tricky.

Comment: @MrMerrick I am not aware of any really good documentation for this. Global variables are hard to understand by their very nature. You might try my plugin [T5 WP Load Order](https://gist.github.com/toscho/4055044). I made that to understand when which file, variable etc. is available.

Comment: Thanks a lot Toscho, will take a look at your plugin and get a better grasp of what's happening behind the scenes. Much appreciated!